# How can I get an image selection programmatically?

Tags: applescript, command-line, preview, graphics

I need to log the bounding box of the selected area from an image to the command line.

This is because I will have to do this across a number of images and then compare and reuse those bounding boxes.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
get_bounding_box.sh
```

and see output like this:

```
+100+20+1400x1000
```

for a selectionoffset by 100 and 20 pixels from top left, and 1400 pixels wide and 1000 tall.

I can use Preview, Photoshop or Gimp, and am comfortable with Applescript, bash.

For example, in Preview, I would be able to get the selection bounding box shown below:

[image: Preview example]

and get `188x207` (the size of the selection bounding box) plus information about the selection's offset via command line.

That way I could use that as an input to other scripts - mostly via ImageMagick.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you add some details about what you want to do? How is the bounding box defined, what exactly do you want to select?

Comment: @nohillside - edited the question to provide an example.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631689/cropping-images-using-command-line-tools-only) forum post which seems to deal with the same problem and uses ImageMagick which you already have